# Shape mismatch error in marplot lib graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to make some `matplot` plots.
I am getting a `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape` error. any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = 12
y2 = 5
korea_scores = (y1, y2)
col_count = 3
bar_width = .2
index = np.arange(col_count)
plt.bar(index, korea_scores, bar_width, alpha=.4, label="Korea")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index = n.arange(col_count)` create three column whereas we only have two column.
Here the edited code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = 12
y2 = 5
korea_scores = (y1, y2)
col_count = 3
bar_width = .2
index = np.arange(col_count-1)
plt.bar(index, korea_scores, bar_width, alpha=.4, label="Korea")
plt.show()
```